# Postfix matches SASL username and not the FROM mail field with smtpd_sender_login_maps

Tags: debian, email, postfix, ldap, debian-stretch

I have already read hundreds of posts all over the internet and I couldn't find anything that solves my problem. So I decided to write this post and hope somebody can help me. First I want to apologize for my bad English I hope you understand what I mean, if not don't bother to ask questions back.

**Problem:**

I have a problem with limiting sasl authenticated users to send mails just from the postfix configuration. I know  that this can be accomplished by using the "reject_sender_login_mismatch" and  "smtpd_sender_login_maps" tags in the postfix main.cf.

But the Problem seams that postfix does not matches the FROM mail field  against the smtpd_sender_login_maps instead it matches the sasl username (in my case also a email address). Its clear that this condition is always true because the sasl username exists don't mater what really is written in the FROM field.

I noticed this when I turned on debugging (debug_peer_list = *client ip*) and send a mail from the spoofed address any_other@any_other.xy with Thunderbird to recipient@domain.xy.  I don't see the real FROM field in the mail.log instead the sasl login (sasl_user@domain.xy) is interpreted as FROM address.

Extract form /var/log/mail.log:

```
....
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: watchdog_pat: 0xXXXXXXXXX
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: < unknown[XXXXXXXXX]: AUTH PLAIN XXXXXXXXX
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: query milter states for other event
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: milter8_other_event: milter local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: xsasl_dovecot_server_first: sasl_method PLAIN, init_response XXXXXXXXX
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: OK?1?user=sasl_user@domain.xy?
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: > unknown[XXXXXXXXX]: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: watchdog_pat: 0xXXXXXXXXX
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: < unknown[XXXXXXXXX]: MAIL FROM:<sasl_user@domain.xy> BODY=8BITMIME SIZE=443
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: extract_addr: input: <sasl_user@domain.xy>
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=sasl_user@domain.xy
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: connect to subsystem private/rewrite
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: send attr request = rewrite
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: send attr rule = local
postfix/smtps/smtpd[3525]: send attr address = ""
....
```

When I grep over the syslog and mail.log for the real FROM address don't find anything to:

```
root@XXXXXX:/etc/postfix# cat /var/log/syslog /var/log/mail.log  |grep -i any_other@any_other.xy
```

**Configurations:**

root@XXXXXX:/etc/postfix# postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps =
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 3h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
local_transport = error:Local Transport Disabled
luser_relay = webmaster@XXXXXX
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 20480000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = XXXXXX, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, autoreply.XXXXXX
mydomain = XXXXXX
myhostname = XXXXXX
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 XXXXXX/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP XXXXXX (Linux)
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_multi_recipient_bounce
smtpd_delay_reject = no
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch permit_mynetworks reject_unknown_recipient_domain check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12340 reject_unauth_destination check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf permit_sasl_authenticated check_sender_ns_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net reject_rbl_client pbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client xbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org reject_rbl_client bl.spamcannibal.org permit
smtpd_reject_footer = For assistance, write webmaster@XXXXXX. Please provide the following information in your problem report: time ($localtime), client ($client_address) client Port ($client_port) and server ($server_name).
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated check_sender_ns_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net reject_unauth_destination permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_user_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unlisted_sender, reject_unauth_pipelining,
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/sslcert/server.crt
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = ${config_directory}/certs/dh_1024.pem
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = ${config_directory}/certs/dh_512.pem
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/sslcert/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5 , DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_session_cache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = yes
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transports
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_alias_maps-vacation.cf ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-virtual_alias_maps-forward.cf proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_aliases.cf ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_mail_distribution.cf ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_mail_redirect.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_recipients.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

cat /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
...
...
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
...
```

cat /etc/postfix/ldap_user_maps.cf

```
bind = yes
bind_dn = xxxx
bind_pw = xxxx
server_host = ldaps://domain.xy:636
search_base = dc=xxxx,dc=xxxx
query_filter = (&(mail=%s))
result_attribute = mail, uid, AlternateAddress
```

Sourcode from the spoofed mail

```
Return-Path: <sasl_user@domain.xy>
X-Original-To: recipient@domain.xy
Delivered-To: recipient@domain.xy
Received: from localhost (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [127.0.0.1])
    by XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (Postfix) with ESMTP id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    for <recipient@domain.xy>; Thu, 10 Aug 2017 20:15:39 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id XXXXXX-XXXXXX for <recipient@domain.xy>;
    Thu, 10 Aug 2017 20:15:39 +0000 (UTC)
Received-SPF: Softfail (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; helo=[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]; envelope-from=sasl_user@domain.xy; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Received: from [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] (unknown [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX])
    (Authenticated sender: sasl_user@domain.xy)
    by XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id XXXXXXXX
    for <recipient@domain.xy>; Thu, 10 Aug 2017 20:15:38 +0000 (UTC)
To: Recipient <recipient@domain.xy>
From: Any other user <any_other@any_other.xy>
Subject: sdfsdf
Message-ID: <6xxx5ab6-7x1c-4x3b-55x6-ab8ba3xxxx1@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 22:15:36 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:51.2) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/51.8.16
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US
```

If you need more information don't bother asking. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think you mean to say "don't bother" asking for more information. I think you mean to say, "if you need more information, just ask." You've done a good job and providing information, but you didn't clearly state what your end result is. Why does this matter to you? Why is this a problem? What are you trying accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your notes. Its a problem because I need to prevent users from sending mails pretending to be some one else in an business environment this is not acceptable. If you look in to the sourcecode of the mail its easy to see who is the real sender, but for "normal" users who just look into the FROM field its not perceptible.

Answer (score 1):

there's a difference between the header field **From:** and the MAIL FROM: command.

as you can see in your example from the header field **Return-Path:** it was sent from `<sasl_user@domain.xy>`, which postfix checked for.

while it may be possible to have postfix check if the From: field corresponds to MAIL FROM: - it may not always be favourable (cf. [Legitimate reasons SMTP “MAIL FROM:” will not match “From:” Header in DATA](https://serverfault.com/questions/518119/legitimate-reasons-smtp-mail-from-will-not-match-from-header-in-data)).

also in order to ensure authenticity it is probably better to have your users use mail encryption/signing via S/MIME or OpenPGP. (cf. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995740(v=exchg.65).aspx)