# Forged FROM: header despite reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch

Tags: postfix, smarthost

**structural description**

- Server A runs postfix and acts as smarthost for server B (also running postfix), reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch is set and works (almost) as expected, see below
- Client C's MUA sends mails via Server A
- B and C both connect via submission port and authentificate with STARTTLS

**what happens when trying to forge sender**

- Setting an arbitrary FROM: header by changing the sender address in thunderbird or adding a new identity in roundcube leads to the expected result: the mail is declined
- doing the same using `mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: forged_address@example.net"` on Server B using A as Smarthost results in successfully sending the mail

**observed differences**

The following was observed by increasing the verbosity of postfix' smtpd

- thunderbird and roundcube login and then directly set the `FROM:`to an accepted value
- Server B starts in the same way but somehow manages to change the `FROM:` header afterwards. This cannot be seen in postfix smtpd logfile but in the mail which is finally sent:

  ```
  Return-Path: <valid_address@example.com>
  Delivered-To: herrhannes@example.com
  Received: from mail.example.com 
  by mail.example.com (Dovecot) with LMTP id UuV2IVaP3lvdKAAAEby5rg
  for <herrhannes@example.com>; Sun, 04 Nov 2018 07:19:02 +0100
  To: herrhannes@example.com
  Subject: This is a Subject
  From: forged_address@example.com
  MIME-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
  Message-Id: <20181104061902.15A9F4A9@debian.example.com>
  Date: Sun,  4 Nov 2018 07:19:02 +0100 (CET)
  Authentication-Results: ORIGINATING;
      auth=pass smtp.auth=valid_address@example.com 
  smtp.mailfrom=valid_address@example.com


  body of your email
  ```

  - at least it is not (as opposed to valid mails) DKIM signed
  - This is not spam, I just do not want that "everybody" is able to forge sender addresses

**questions**

- Why does this happen?
- More important: What can I do to prevent it happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, as the SMTP *envelope sender* and `From:` header are separate things. The [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) (and the version limited to authenticated users only) prevents using an address in SMTP `MAIL FROM` command unless it matches an SASL authenticated owner. It doesn't care what's inside the message – that's including its headers. That's how email was designed, and there are also many [legitimate reasons for this mismatch](https://serverfault.com/questions/518119/legitimate-reasons-smtp-mail-from-will-not-match-from-header-in-data).

When using `mail -a` you modify the headers, alone. It's not changed afterwards, as you suggest. The only reason you can't do this with Thunderbird is that it uses the same address in both envelope and header.  It's not limited by your server.

Comment: Thunderbird does not *always* use the same address in both envelope and header. Afaik mismatches are always caused by bugs, but since those have not been resolved for years, one should not depend on Thunderbird behaving one way or another.

Comment: Aaah.That explains it a lot. Although it is not what I would have wanted to hear. Thank you very much! I would have thought this was somehow related.

Comment: This is not really a problem as the envelope sender is recorded to `Return-Path` and to the logs. If you suspect someone using this feature illegitimately (e.g. you receive abuse reports), you can always suspend their accounts.

Comment: Yes that is correct. And abuse is really improbable, as it is my private mail server. It's just sort of a cosmetic issue.

Comment: As a footnote: << As of Postfix 2.1, this is an alias for "reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch". >>  So Postfix admins now can handle unauthed users differently.