# Rewrite email (RFC822) From address to match MAIL FROM (RFC821) envelope address postfix

Tags: postfix, spoofing

I'm taking steps to harden my outgoing postfix SMTP server.  I want to prevent users from spoofing their sender address.

When sending email with postfix SMTP the sender is identified in three ways:

1. In the email itself there is a `From:` header - as defined in [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822)
2. When sending with SMTP there is a `MAIL FROM` address - as defined in [RFC 821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc821)
3. When logging into postfix (SMTP) a client specifies a username which can also be interpreted as the sender

Looking in the manual, I believe that [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) and [reject_unlisted_sender](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unlisted_sender) will together guarantee that the `MAIL FROM` email as associated with the postifx login.  That's 2 and 3 above match.

I'm stuck on how to ensure that all three match.  I'm happy if the result just re-writes the message rather than rejecting but either would be fine.  However I don't see a way to do this.  I can see that [cleanup](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) will add a missing `From:` header but I see no way to check and rewrite one.

---

Thanks to those who pointed out [another similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/286070/how-to-limit-the-from-header-to-match-mail-from-in-postfix).  Unfortunately this has been of no help as the question has two answers, one is very vague the other appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time looking into this and I can't find a pure postfix way.  The one suggestion of using `header_checks` doesn't seem to work because you can't (AFAIK) match one header against another.

What is possible is to write your own program / script to perform the check for you and use this as a [content_filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

---

## Step 1

Here's a simplified version of the one I use written in python.  This reads an email from the stdin taking `MAIL from` and `RECPT to` addresses as arguments.  It checks the `From:` header against the `MAIL from` and replaces it if they don't match.  I save this as `/usr/share/mail_filter/filter.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import subprocess
import email.parser
import email.policy

parser = email.parser.BytesParser(policy=email.policy.default)
message = parser.parse(sys.stdin.buffer)

envelope_from = sys.argv[1]
envelope_to = sys.argv[2]
# This if statement checks envelope from against message from
if message['From'].addresses[0].addr_spec != envelope_from:
    print(f"Replacing sender {message['from']} with {envelope_from}", file=sys.stderr)
    message.replace_header('From', envelope_from)

# sendmail -G -i -f sender@sender_domain.tld recipient@recipient_domain.tld
sendmail = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-Gif", envelope_from, envelope_to], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
with sendmail.stdin:
    sendmail.stdin.write(message.as_bytes())

# If sendmail returns an error, cascade it back to postfix
sys.exit(sendmail.wait())
```

## Step 2

Updated `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
# added the -o content_filter...
smtp inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=filter:dummy

# Added this entire service
filter    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
  flags=Rq user=filter null_sender=
  argv=/usr/share/mail_filter/filter.py ${sender} ${recipient}
```

*Note this references the script location from step 1 and the user defined in step 3*

## Step 3

I added an OS user `filter` in a group with access to use `sendmail`.

```
useradd --system --gid postdrop filter
```

## Caveats

As per the [instructions](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) simple filters (passing forward using `sendmail`) can only be applied to SMTP clients and cannot filter messages sent via sendmail.  If this is a problem for you then you would need to write an [advanced content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter).